# Conditionally updating child component's state in event-handler passed by Parent-class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

```
const Child = (props) => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(props.val);

  const handleCreate = (newData) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            {
                const transactions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tableData));
                const clean_transaction = getCleanTransaction(newData);
                const db_transaction = convertToDbInterface(clean_transaction);
                transactions.push(clean_transaction);
// The below code makes post-request to 2 APIs synchronously and conditionally updates the child-state if calls are successful.
                **categoryPostRequest(clean_transaction)
                    .then(category_res => {
                        console.log('cat-add-res:', category_res);
                        transactionPostRequest(clean_transaction)
                            .then(transaction_res => {
                                addToast('Added successfully', { appearance: 'success'});
                                **setVal(transactions)**
                            }).catch(tr_err => {
                            addToast(tr_err.message, {appearance: 'error'});
                        })
                    }).catch(category_err => {
                    console.log(category_err);
                    addToast(category_err.message, {appearance: 'error'})
                });**
            }
            resolve()
        }, 1000)
    });

  return (
    <MaterialTable
            title={props.title}
            data={val}
            editable={{
                onRowAdd: handleCreate
            }}
        />
  );
}

const Parent = (props) => {
  // some other stuff to generate val
  return (
    <Child val={val}/>
  );
}
```

I am struggling to achieve this:
I'd like to move the post-request part of the function in handleCreate (bold-section), over to the Parent-component that can be called by the Child-class. 
The idea is to make the Component abstract and re-usable by other similar Parent-classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the function in the parent, and pass it to the child in the props:

```
const Parent = (props) => {
  // The handler
  const onCreate = /*...*/;

  // some other stuff
  return (
    <Child ...props onCreate={onCreate}/>
  );
}
```

Then have the child call the function with any parameters it needs (there don't seem to be any in your example, you're not using `val` in it for instance):

```
return (
  <MaterialTable
          title={props.title}
          data={val}
          editable={{
              onRowAdd: props.onCreate // Or `onRowAdd: () => props.onCreate(parameters, go, here)`
          }}
      />
);
```

---

Side note: There's no reason to copy `props.val` to `val` state member within the child component, just use `props.val`.

Side note 2: Destructuring is often handy with props:

```
const Child = ({val, onCreate}) => {
  // ...
};
```

Side note 3: You have your `Parent` component calling `Child` with **all** of its props, via `...props`:

```
return (
  <Child ...props onCreate={onCreate}/>
);
```

That's generally not best. Only pass `Child` what it actually needs, in this case, `val` and `onCreate`:

```
return (
  <Child val={props.val} onCreate={onCreate}/>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your post.
I noticed and made some modifications to the code to make it more understandable.
Pardon me if I am missing your point, I do understand we can pass the function as prop to the Child, but I do want to update the setVal (child-state) conditionally when the api-requests are successful.

Comment: @SerialLazer - That doesn't change the fundamental thing above, that you pass a function to the child that knows how to do the update. But note that copying props to state and then modifying them is usually not best practice; the parent should just render the child with the new prop value instead. (That's almost exactly the same thing as the child changing a state member.) If you really need to compute state from props, see [this documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops) on the React site.

Comment: I agree maintaining the state here in the child-component might be an anti-pattern of sorts. My main motivation was to abstract the re-usable code to a Child-component. So if I move the val,setVal and other stuff to Parent-component, I wouldnt really need a Child-component at all.

Comment: @SerialLazer - It's the same as anything, abstract it if it's a useful abstraction, don't if it isn't. :-)